# How to make the first item of the list always be at the top and the rest of the list will scroll independently of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to position the first item of a list to the top of the list and do not scroll with other items?

```
     <Select
            open={open}
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
            onClose={this.handleSelectClose}
            onOpen={this.handleSelectOpen}
          >
            <MenuItem
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
              }}
            >
              <TextField
                value={search}
                fullWidth
                placeholder="search"
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
            </MenuItem>
            {filteredOptions.length ? (
              filteredOptions.map(option => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem value={option} key={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })
            ) : (
              <MenuItem disabled>No match</MenuItem>
            )}
     </Select>
```

It can look like an autocomplete on the https://sharlaan.github.io/example3

Comment: link is not working. I guess it is pointing to a private repo.

Answer (score 1):

From a UX point of view I wouldn't place the search field inside the list... Why don't you take the Autocomplete component of Material-UI directly? In this case you would have a normal text field which opens the corresponding list, once the user starts typing.
See https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/ for an example how to use it...

If you want to have a more complex select component I can recommend React-Select (https://react-select.com). But if you want it to match the Material look & feel, you would have to style it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

link is not working and I don't see you example. However, here is the example of the style you need in such a case:

```
Select
position: relative // necessary
height: 123px // optional
overflow-y: scroll // optional

MenuItem // first one only
position: absolute // necessary
top: 0px // optional
z-index:10 // optional
background-color: white // optional
```